# Magento2 Edit styles-i.css

Tags: magento2, css

Can anyone help me to edit styles-i.css in magento2
It is showing the path in pub directory but no structure in design theme files

Thanks

Comment: This is a complied file - to wit, it comes from many sources.

Answer (score 2):

This file is automatically generated. Magento uses LESS as CSS preprocessor.

The concept is explained here: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css-preprocess.html

And here's a guide for customizing: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/css-guide/css_quick_guide_approach.html